# related dropdown list

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP.. I need your help..

I have 2 dropdownlist that related:

dropdown 1 : manually insert the value

dropdown 2 : attach value from database (value based on condition that selected in dropdown 1)

Then, both value which are selected will display in textbox at another form.

My problem is:

1) The value in 2nd dropdown can't be display.

2) The value in 1st dropdown can pass to other form but the 2nd can't.

Please kindly guide me.

I don't know how to share my code here.

form1.php

//1st dropdown

```
<select name="fruit_name" id="fruit_name" style="font-family: Calibri;font-size: 10pt;" onchange="loadXMLDoc(this.value); ">
   <option value="0">-- please choose --</option>
   <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option>
   <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
```

//2nd dropdown

```
        $fruit_name = $_POST['fruit_name'];
#Connect to MySQL
#Connect to database

$result = mysql_query("SELECT colour FROM fruit WHERE fruit_name = '$fruit_name'");

echo "<select name='colour' id='colour' style='font-family: Calibri;font-size: 10pt;'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo "<option value = ''>" . $row['colour'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

mysql_free_result($result);

//Closes specified connection
?>
```

form2.php

```
 <?php
//connection

        $fruit_name = $_POST['fruit_name'];
        $colour = $_POST['colour'];
?>
  <label>
  <input type="text" name="fruit_name" id="fruit_name" value = "<?php echo $fruit_name;?>" readonly>
  </label>
  <p>
    <label>
    <input type="text" name="colour" id="colour" value="<?php echo $colour;?>" readonly>
    </label>
  </p>
```

Comment: where's the code? no1 will answer your question if you didn't posted the relevant code

Comment: Ajax is your answer. Here is little something to get you started http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript

Comment: Please put some code for better answers

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know how to share my code here.

Comment: Edit your question and paste the code into it. Then use the `{}` tool to mark it as code so it will be formatted properly.

Comment: @sofiasofi select the relevant code to your problem and copy it. Then edit your question, paste the code, select it all and press `Ctrl`+`K`.

Comment: i've edit my question. tq for your guide.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't do this but since I've some spare time on hand right now, I'm going to give the general approach that you can follow:

Include the following between your `<head>` tag.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Below that, paste this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('select#fruit_name').change(function(){
                var selectedVal = $(this).val(); // get the selected value

                $.ajax({    // send ajax request to the php file to process data
                    type:'post',
                    url:'php-page-name.php',
                    data:{'value':selectedVal},
                    success:function(ret)   // display the result from php-page-name.php page
                    {
                        $('div#result').html(ret);
                    }
                });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Lets move on to your **HTML** now

```
    <select name="fruit_name" id="fruit_name" style="font-family: Calibri;font-size: 10pt;">
   <option value="0">-- please choose --</option>
   <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option>
   <option value="Apple">Apple</option> 
   </select>

<div id="result">
    <select>
        <option>Select One</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**php-page-name.php** page (Do not forget to create this page and put it in the same folder as form1.php)

```
    <?php
    // put the code to connect to your database here


    $fruit_name = $_POST['value'];  // this will contain the value selected from first dropdown

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT colour FROM fruit WHERE fruit_name = '$fruit_name'");

echo "<select name='colour' id='colour' style='font-family: Calibri;font-size: 10pt;'>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<option value = '".$row['colour']."'>" . $row['colour'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

mysql_free_result($result);
    ?>
```

PS : I'm using the `mysql_*` functions in this example since I'm assuming you're too. But this is not recommended as they are going to be deprecated soon. You might want to switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: thank you @asprin. i've tried your code but i have this error
- Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context


may i know about the error?

Comment: I've edited my answer using your values. Check it out. ALso make sure you create a php page called `php-page-name.php` and put it in the same folder as the one in which the first drodown is present.

Comment: thank you @asprin. I've used it but i have this error
- Warning: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

at mysql_free_result($result); code.

Comment: i've edit the code. now, after i choose the 1st dropdown, the 2nd dropdown value not display. but after i choose the 1st dropdown and submit it, the value for second 2nd dropdown will be display.

can you help me to make it display after i choose 1st value without submit it?